# My Regular Expression is not working

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the string i am trying to match

```
"NNNN.[LOOP]S[SENSOR] [TEXT]"
```

Here is the RegEx i am using

```
"NNNN.([^\n\r/.]*)S([^\n\r/.]*) ([^\n\r/.]*)"
```

I want this to match
"[LOOP]", "[SENSOR]" and "[TEXT]"

However it matches "[LOOP]S[SEN", "OR]" and "[TEXT]"

Please send help

Comment: Learn about "greedy regular expressions": http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: Try matching the square brackets in your regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
NNNN\.(\[[^\s]+\])S(\[[^\s]+\])\s(\[[^\s]+\])
```

Note that you have to escape the dot "." and the square brackets "[" "]"

This will match: **NNNN** string, followed by a dot **\.** followed by a string (that doesn't contains spaces) between brackets **(\[[^\s]+\])**, followed by an **S**, followed by another string between brackets **(\[[^\s]+\])**, followed by a single space **\s**, followed by a third string between brackets **(\[[^\s]+\])**.